# How to disable CUPS spooling and print directly?

Tags: cups

On my machine runs cups. I have setup a few printers which are provided by a printserver (VPSX). When I print a few jobs they are stored in the local (CUPS) printspooler and only one job is sent. The next one is sent not until the latter is finished. I want to achieve that they are all just sent to the printserver, which should take care of spooling. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the CUPS options `waitjob` and `waitprinter`, as I described in an answer to a similar question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156489/cups-send-multiple-jobs-to-ipp-printer